# oracle needs me to tell it how many rows to select for query to succeed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

EDIT: "some_table" (below) turns out to be a view rather than a table

Alright this seems outrageous but here it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE some_conditions;
```

The result is *715*.

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM some_table WHERE some_conditions;
```

The result is I abort the query after 5 minutes.

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM some_table WHERE some_conditions AND rownum <= 716;
```

The result is I abort the query after 5 minutes.

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c FROM some_table WHERE some_conditions AND rownum <= 715;
```

The result is I get my data in 2 seconds. BUT what you might expect given the count result and the rownum condition (namely, 715 rows returned) isn't what you get: you get 79 rows.

**So I have two questions:**

1. Why might Oracle grind away indefinitely (where indefinitely means more than 5 minutes) on the "rownum <= 716" query but return very fast on the "rownum <= 715" query? Indeed, if it is in fact returning all available results in 2 seconds in the latter case, why does the query with no rownum condition in the WHERE clause go on indefinitely?
2. Why might the COUNT(*) return 715, and my "rownum <= 715" query produce only 79 rows?

**Disclaimers:**

1. I've been very vague with the actual details of the table in questions, etc... this is for security. If some additional information would actually improve anyone's ability to analyze the situation let me know what that information is and I hope I can provide it.
2. I haven't analyzed the query plans involved because... I can't. Apparently I lack the necessary privileges. I don't see this changing, I'm in a locked down corporate environment.
3. I'm new to Oracle but not RDBMSs (I've used SQL Server for a number of years). I'm still learning about Oracle and it's entirely possible my actions have been full of obvious stupidity- if this is the case please tell me so I know, don't just sneer at me and navigate to a different question!

**Follow-ups to Questions**

@MJB: It is in fact a view. A view with 274 columns :s I don't know if the view is indexed, is there a query on the System Catalog that would tell me (I queried on ALL_INDEXES with no result returned)?

@MJB 2: I am able to get the source by querying ALL_VIEWS.TEXT; I used the following query in Toad:

```
set LONG 10000 select TEXT from ALL_VIEWS where VIEW_NAME = :view and OWNER=:owner;
```

My question is, the output seems to have a bunch of lines like:

TEXT
(a row of hyphens appears on the next line; including that here just makes the word TEXT bold however...)

separating the output. If I get rid of all these and rejoin the text, will I have the complete definition or is it possible that I'm seeing some truncated version? The "set LONG 10000" part of the query is something I found on Google and it might as well be a magic spell as far as my understanding of it goes.

UPDATE: A co-worker has shown me the view definition (it's a star schema being joined up into one big flat view) and informed me that there are nearly no indexes. Apparently development was outsourced...

Under the circumstances I'm less surprised that there are surpise performance cliffs, but I'm not sure why the COUNT(*) would be in conflict with the number of rows returned when I specify the 'WHERE rownum <= 715' clause. Is it possible the count is being performed using statistics and that those statistics are simply not up to providing a better result?

Given the nature of the underlying tables I'm inclined to write this situation off as poor development leading to unexpected and nasty surprises. As others have pointed out in the comments, I'm not really in a position to do any experimenting or fixing.

Comment: Can you see which indexes exist? I have no idea what they are preventing by stopping you from running EXPLAIN PLAN, but whatever. Also, is "some_table" really a table or is it a view?

Comment: Sometimes, second time execution of a query will be faster, considering `cache` into account. So, <=715 was hanging.. and then the <=716 query results might be already available.!! And about the  79 rows returned. probably, only 79 rows are qualified for your filter condition.

Comment: Can you see the source of the view? I'm thinking that you'll have to find the indexes on the base tables. That may still not solve your problem, but that is the way I would look into it. I think that 11g allows indexes on views, but I suspect you have to check for both (index(es) on the view itself and index(es) on the underlying tables).

Comment: @OracleUser: if only 79 rows qualified for the filter, why did the count(*) (with the same filter) return 715? Also, I don't buy the caching argument because it doesn't matter how many times or in what order I run the queries the result is the same.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I cannot be sure, but it sounds like your view text merely has comments inside (comments starting with double hyphens). You are correct that the field TEXT is a long field. SQLPlus (and Toad I assume) return only a portion of a LONG field by default, so you are doing the right thing to set it high. So when you did that, did the SELECT statement make sense? Can you see all the tables in use? Can you find if there are appropriate indexes on those tables?

Comment: Are table statistics that far off? (have DBA's check)

Comment: @Paul: you should change `some_table` to `some_view` in your question.  I had to read through it until I got to the followup questions to discover it was on a view and not a table -- this changes the question quite a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible it is in your situation, but RLS policies (http://www.vsevolod.com/magz/ORplSQLl/0596005873/oracleplsqldba-chp-5-sect-3.html) may cause 'select someColumn' query to return less rows that select count(*) would indicate.

Comment: So if you don't have the privileges to run an Explain Plan why do you care?  You're not going to have the privileges to fix anything.  Boot this problem up to a DBA or senior developer, anyone who does have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Is `col_a, col_b, col_c` a function?

Comment: This was probably predicate pushing changing the execution plan of the query; 715/716 just happens to be the magical numbers where the plan changes.  And the new plan probably hit an unknown Oracle bug.  Without a lot more information we can only speculate.